# Variables undefined error in latest version of localhost (vertrigo_230)

Tags: php, localhost

Below mentioned PHP code was perfect on vertrigo_222 (and also on livehost).

Now I am trying to upgrade my localhost to vertrigo_230.

I am facing following undefined variable error or warning:
[image]
Here is code (line # 30 is mentioned):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once("PHP_Code/db_connection.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['data']))
    $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

//Fetch All Important Information from Database in Variables
if($_SESSION['id'] && $_SESSION['pw'])  //Login Must for This Informatiion
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['city_id']))
    {
        if($_REQUEST['city_id'])
        {
            $city_id = $_REQUEST['city_id'];
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[id]'";
            $c = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
            $city = mysql_fetch_array($c);
            $city_id = $city['city_id'];
        }
        //Setting Current/Opened City in Session
        $_SESSION['city_id'] = $city_id;
    }
}

//Secure Page
if($data == "")                   //Line # 30
    $data = "loginPage";
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: mysql_* functions are now deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the `$data`  as global variable and you have to use `mysqli` insted because `mysql` Officially deprecated

```
  ob_start();
session_start();
include_once("PHP_Code/db_connection.php");
$data = '';
//your code
```